# Why is transaction reverting with no additional error details?

Tags: evm, contract-debugging, polygon

I don't understand how people can debug transactions when there are no error details shown.

[Here is a recent transaction I submitted to Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0x48abe95da0f524563691f30cbd1b01f873edb22ee6f899d8c331fe1e7a921665&type=gethtrace2):

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't in any way indicate what error has occured. All it says is that the transaction was reverted, with no additional context.

How can I dig into this transaction and get more details?

I tried using the Remix Debugger as well, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

Before submitting this transaction, I was warned that it was likely to fail. As you can see, this warning gives no information either:

[image]

As you can see the data field holds a garbage value rather than error codes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the ABI if it's useful/necessary for debugging:

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "contract IERC20",
                "name": "inputToken",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "contract IERC20",
                "name": "outputToken",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "targetPriceNumerator",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "targetPriceDenominator",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "minimumExecution",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "execute",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "failsafe_withdraw_input",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "failsafe_withdraw_output",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

**Edit**: Function code:

```
    function execute() public {
        require(block.number - _lastExecutionBlockNumber >= 41400, "Can only be executed every 23 hours.");
        _lastExecutionBlockNumber = block.number;
        
        (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1,) = _pair.getReserves();
        uint inputReserve = _inputIndex == 0 ? reserve0 : reserve1;
        uint outputReserve = _outputIndex == 0 ? reserve0 : reserve1;
        uint inputAmount = (_sqrt((_targetPriceNumerator * inputReserve * outputReserve) / _targetPriceDenominator) * _targetPriceDenominator) / _targetPriceNumerator - inputReserve;
        
        require(_inputToken.balanceOf(address(this)) >= inputAmount, "Insufficient funds.");
        require(inputAmount >= _minimumExecution, "Less than minimum execution.");
        _inputToken.approve(address(_router), inputAmount);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(_inputToken);
        path[1] = address(_outputToken);
        uint outputAmount = _router.swapExactTokensForTokens(inputAmount, 0 /* safe because of inputAmount calculation */, path, address(this), block.timestamp)[1];

        _inputToken.approve(address(_router), 2 ** 256 - 1);
        _outputToken.approve(address(_router), outputAmount);
        uint outputTokenAmount = outputAmount;
        uint inputTokenAmount = (outputTokenAmount * inputReserve) / outputReserve;
        _router.addLiquidity(address(_inputToken), address(_outputToken), inputTokenAmount, outputTokenAmount, inputTokenAmount, outputTokenAmount, _owner, block.timestamp);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the function code for the call you were trying to execute?

Comment: @AaronKlich I've done that. Without the function code, shouldn't I still be able to figure out the error? The reason why it was reverted?

Comment: The thing is , solidity's runtime errors arent precise , if the blockchain encounters a problem executing a function it reverts with no explanation unless you read the error with a require command. without a require command the revertion most of the times has no explanation. however with my experiences when youre warned about an error before executing a function, its 99% of the times due to an error you made within the function code that is only noticeable during runtime, that is why i asked for your code

Comment: @AaronKlich Ok I wasn't aware of that. Can you see anything wrong with my code? Is there some way of debugging the transaction by simulating re-running it in a way that shows the error message?

Comment: @AaronKlich Normally I would test this transaction locally with something like truffle, but I figure that wouldn't work out too well since I'm integrating with QuickSwap and I want to test the live version.

Answer (score 7):

"output": "0x4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000***11***"

```
0x01: If you call assert with an argument that evaluates to false.
0x11: If an arithmetic operation results in underflow or overflow outside of an unchecked { ... } block.
0x12: If you divide or modulo by zero (e.g. 5 / 0 or 23 % 0).
0x21: If you convert a value that is too big or negative into an enum type.
0x31: If you call .pop() on an empty array.
0x32: If you access an array, bytesN or an array slice at an out-of-bounds or negative index (i.e. x[i] where i >= x.length or i < 0).
0x41: If you allocate too much memory or create an array that is too large.
0x51: If you call a zero-initialized variable of internal function type.
```

Comment: That is useful information thank you

Answer (score 2):

From the transaction trace it did a single externall call and reverted.

```
  "type": "CALL",
  "from": "0xa3bab7a95ed40c2a62c7a1ac4ef2043f8b7a1cb6",
  "to": "0x51bc0f8a859fc64c69df3e8802dd6ed2709904a7",
  "value": "0x0",
  "gas": "0x2d7478",
  "gasUsed": "0x13dc5",
  "input": "0x61461954",
  "output": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011",
  "error": "execution reverted",
  "time": "127.9954ms",
  "calls": [
    {
      "type": "STATICCALL",
      "from": "0x51bc0f8a859fc64c69df3e8802dd6ed2709904a7",
      "to": "0xcb33a1f36adb14fa90c983e9edee99961e20f426",
      "gas": "0x2c5d89",
      "gasUsed": "0x9c8",
      "input": "0x0902f1ac",
      "output": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004339e9e4050da71e50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040820b96f69ecf45e79500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000611e9cfe"
    }
  ]
```

From the source code the first external call is `_pair.getReserves()` and the second is `_inputToken.balanceOf()`, so somewhere between those is the error. Probably it is in `inputAmount` computation.

```
function execute() public {
    require(block.number - _lastExecutionBlockNumber >= 41400, "Can only be executed every 23 hours.");
    _lastExecutionBlockNumber = block.number;
    
    (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1,) = _pair.getReserves();
    uint inputReserve = _inputIndex == 0 ? reserve0 : reserve1;
    uint outputReserve = _outputIndex == 0 ? reserve0 : reserve1;
    uint inputAmount = (_sqrt((_targetPriceNumerator * inputReserve * outputReserve) / _targetPriceDenominator) * _targetPriceDenominator) / _targetPriceNumerator - inputReserve;
    
    require(_inputToken.balanceOf(address(this)) >= inputAmount, "Insufficient funds.");
    require(inputAmount >= _minimumExecution, "Less than minimum execution.");
    _inputToken.approve(address(_router), inputAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. That is a nice way of narrowing down where the error came from.